# PHP MySQL dates not working

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a query that is supposed to be inserting data into a MySQL date field.

The incoming data is formatted as MM/DD/YYYY. I run it through this function:

```
$birthday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data[16]));
```

When I use var_dump to see what it looks like it, return YYYY-MM-DD which is correct. The issue is that when I go to insert it into the field it always returns 0000-00-00. What gives?

The insert code:

```
INSERT INTO customers (email_address, confirm_email_address, 
full_name, phone_number, status,time, company, industry,fax, 
alternate_email_address, address, address2, city, state, zip_code, 
country, birthdate, repid, salesrep, secId) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'%s','1','%s','%s','%s','%s',‌​'%s','%s','%s',
'USA','%d','%d','%d','%d')
```

Comment: What does your `INSERT` statement look like?

Comment: `INSERT INTO 

customers (email_address, confirm_email_address, full_name, phone_number, status,time, company, industry,fax, alternate_email_address, address, address2,
city, state, zip_code, country, birthdate, repid, salesrep, secId)
       VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'%s','1','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','USA','%d','%d','%d','%d')`

Comment: you're using %d for the birthdate field. should be %s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count your fields backwards in the values assignments. You're using %d for the birthdate field, which means expect a digit. Change that to %s for string and you should be ok.

```
INSERT INTO customers (email_address, confirm_email_address, 
full_name, phone_number, status,time, company, industry,fax, 
alternate_email_address, address, address2, city, state, zip_code, 
country, birthdate, repid, salesrep, secId) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'%s','1','%s','%s','%s','%s',‌​'%s','%s','%s',
'USA','%s','%d','%d','%d')
```